# How to aim and shoot with L1/R1 (PS4) in Battlefield 1?

Tags: battlefield-1

I started playing Battlefield 1 on PS4 yesterday, and one the first thing I did was attempt to change my controls so that I could aim and shoot with L1 and R1, like I've always been doing in other FPS games. I looked for several minutes in the controls menu, but didn't find that option anywhere.

Is it possible to change the controls so that I can aim and shoot with L1/R1 in Battlefield 1?

Comment: Im pretty sure you have to do this via custom button mapping https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaAuHkZYou0

Comment: I didn't know I could do this, that's helpful. It's a bit of a pain to have to switch it back when playing another game though.

Comment: I know there's an in-game option to change controls around, I'd have to look closer at it later today though to see if it's possible.